# Login system, banned user php

Tags: php, mysql, system

I have a mysql column named "banned" with value of 0 if they are not, and a value of 1 if they are, which is inside table "users." Currently this code gives a an error "Incorrect username/password combination!" if a person is banned however I cannot figure out how to get it to say "you are banned" if the value of "banned" is 1.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    session_start();
    // configuration
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "login";
    $dbuser     = ".";
    $dbpass     = ".";

    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
    // new data

    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    // query
    $result = "SELECT id, username, password, banned FROM users WHERE username= :username AND banned = '0'";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($result);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();   
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($user === false){
        //Could not find a user with that username!
        //PS: You might want to handle this error in a more user-friendly manner!
        $error = "Incorrect username/password combination!";
    } else{
        //User account found. Check to see if the given password matches the
        //password hash that we stored in our users table.

        //Compare the passwords.
        $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt, $user['password']);

        //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
        if($validPassword){

       $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header("location: home.php");
            exit;

        } else{
        $error = "Incorrect username/password combination!";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to eliminate things like `=== false` and instead flip that to be `if ($user)` and reverse the order of the blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Do not put a banned check in the query, let the query return the data from database. And then check for the condition if banned == 1 then show the error that the user is banned. So your code should be something like so:

```
$result = "SELECT id, username, password, banned FROM users WHERE username= :username";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($result);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();   
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($user === false){
    $error = "Incorrect username/password combination!";
} else{
    if($user['banned'] == '1')
    {
              //give the banned error and return;
    }
    else
    {
            //Do the login stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need an "else if" in the middle there...

```
if($user === false){
  //Could not find a user with that username!
  //PS: You might want to handle this error in a more user-friendly manner!
  $error = "Incorrect username/password combination!";
} else if ($user['banned'] == 1){
  $error = "Hey! You are banned";
} else {
```